# How to convert Json array complex to List object in android

Tags: android, json, jackson, fasterxml

I have a json string as following, and I need convert to List object in Android.

```
[
  {
    "name":"Name1",
    "images":["http://abc.jpg", "http://aaa.jpg"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Name2",
    "images":["dads", "dsadsd"]
  }
]
```

In Android I declare a Model class with name MyObject.class

```
class MyObject{
    public String name;
    public List<String> images;
}

public void testConvertJson(){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<MyObject> result = mapper.readValue(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.m1), new TypeReference<List<MyObject>);
}
```

Result StackTrace:

```
09-04 22:47:17.961: W/System.err(5854): com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token
09-04 22:47:17.961: W/System.err(5854):  at [Source: android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream@fe387ee; line: 242, column: 13] (through reference chain: com.demo.models.MyObject["images"])
```

Please help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: are you sure R.raw.m1 is having the json string you show to us?

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you can use `Gson` for your issue, like the following:

```
String jsonString = "[\n" +
            "  {\n" +
            "    \"name\":\"Name1\",\n" +
            "    \"images\":[\"http://abc.jpg\", \"http://aaa.jpg\"]\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  {\n" +
            "    \"name\": \"Name2\",\n" +
            "    \"images\":[\"dads\", \"dsadsd\"]\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "]";
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyObject[] object = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyObject[].class);
List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(object));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the method you were using, personally I normally create my own parser.  Likely not the most efficient, but I personally understand it better.

I think this should work.  Should work for any string with a similar format I believe.

```
String mess = getResources().getString(R.raw.m1);
List<MyObject> myObjects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(mess);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
        myObject.name = jsonObject.get("name");

        String arrayOfStringString = jsonObject.get("images");
        arrayOfStringString = arrayOfStringString.replace(" ","").replace("[","").replace("]","");
        String[] images =  ArrayarrayOfStringString.split(",");
        myObject.images = java.util.Arrays.asList(images);

        myObjects.add(myObject);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```